# Get pairs of substrings from a block text and form into an associative array

Tags: php, arrays, xml, associative-array, text-extraction

How can I filter my content and display those values together elsewhere. The content is being loaded in via XML that is being filled by our client. Therefore I can't change the values. The problem is that my values are on different lines. I am currently filtering some values:

```php
if (!empty($arraywithvalues)) {
    $array = explode("<br>", $arraywithvalues);
    foreach( $array as $key => $value){
        if (
            strpos(strtolower($value),'oppervlakte') !== FALSE ||
            strpos(strtolower($value),'perceel') !== FALSE ||
            strpos(strtolower($value),'golf') !== FALSE 
        ) {
            $filtered_content[] = $value;
            unset($array[$key]);
        }
    };
```

This is to filter out the text bit, this is succesfully done as can be seen on [this website](https://willyroks.nl/buildings/building/4879).
Problem is there are still values that need to be filitered out like:

> 20 M2

> 20 km

However the filtering itself is no problem. The problem im running into is putting the values next to one and another.
So for example. Distance till golf (*First filtered value*) - 20km (*Second filtered value*). How can I achieve this?

XML as it gets imported:

```
string(82)"

Bebouwde oppervlakte

80 M2

Terras oppervlakte

20 M2

Keuken oppervlakte

12 M2"
```

Comment: could you provide an example of the XML?

Comment: Sure! I'll include a short example of a line. I personally can't access the XML but I'll put a line how it looks like when it's imported.

Comment: Updated my answer! I've included a few lines of the XML sheet (This is how it looks like when `var_dumped` since this is the closest I could get viewing the XML itself.

Comment: I am not sure I follow...What is the expected outcome?

Comment: Client is sure making it hard if hes typing this, cause its not a valid XML, this is just a text

Comment: He is making it hard, before it just was one line. Guess this is what he prefers. Also on @JureW 's question as said in my question. Outcome is expected to be: Distance till golf - 20km

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**PHP8**

```php
<?php

$values = <<<EOL

Bebouwde oppervlakte

80 M2

Terras oppervlakte

20 M2

Keuken oppervlakte

12 M2
EOL;

if (!$values) {
    // you can throw an exception and/or log etc.
    return;
}

$valueList = array_filter(explode(PHP_EOL, $values));
$valueList = array_values(array_map('trim', $valueList));

$formatedValueList = [];

foreach($valueList as $key => $value) {
    if ((
            str_contains(strtolower($value), 'oppervlakte')
            || str_contains(strtolower($value), 'perceel') 
            || str_contains(strtolower($value), 'golf')
        ) && (
            str_contains(strtolower($valueList[$key+1]), 'm2')
            || str_contains(strtolower($valueList[$key+1]), 'km')
        )
    ) {
        $formatedValueList[] = sprintf('%s - %s', $value, $valueList[$key+1]);
    }
}


var_dump($formatedValueList);
```

**PHP7**

```php
<?php

$values = <<<EOL

Bebouwde oppervlakte

80 M2

Terras oppervlakte

20 M2

Keuken oppervlakte

12 M2
EOL;

if (!$values) {
    // you can throw an exception and/or log etc.
    return;
}

$valueList = array_filter(explode(PHP_EOL, $values));
$valueList = array_values(array_map('trim', $valueList));

$formatedValueList = [];

foreach($valueList as $key => $value) {
    if ((
            strpos(strtolower($value), 'oppervlakte') !== false
            || strpos(strtolower($value), 'perceel')  !== false
            || strpos(strtolower($value), 'golf') !== false
        ) && (
            strpos(strtolower($valueList[$key+1]), 'm2') !== false
            || strpos(strtolower($valueList[$key+1]), 'km') !== false
        )
    ) {
        $formatedValueList[] = sprintf('%s - %s', $value, $valueList[$key+1]);
    }
}


var_dump($formatedValueList);
```

**Output**

```php
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(28) "Bebouwde oppervlakte - 80 M2"
  [1]=>
  string(26) "Terras oppervlakte - 20 M2"
  [2]=>
  string(26) "Keuken oppervlakte - 12 M2"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Provided the records are in sequence as above it is fairly easy. You buffer the first line and then keep reading until the line with the second value comes. Then concatenate buffer and current value.

```
if (!empty($arraywithvalues)) {
    $array = explode("<br>", $arraywithvalues);
    foreach( $array as $value){
        if ( strpos(strtolower($value),'oppervlakte') !== FALSE ||
             strpos(strtolower($value),'perceel') !== FALSE ||
             strpos(strtolower($value),'golf') !== FALSE            ) {
            $buffer = $value;
        } elseif ( strpos(strtolower($value),'m2') !== FALSE ||
                   strpos(strtolower($value),'km') !== FALSE       ) { 
            $filtered_content[] = $buffer . ' - ' . $value;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its a bit sloppy, but I think it gets the job done :

```
<?php

$stringArray = explode("\r\n", trim($arraywithvalues));
$stringArray = array_filter($stringArray);
$stringArray = array_values($stringArray);

$newArray = [];
foreach($stringArray as $key => $value) {
    if($key % 2 == 0)
        $newArray[$value] = '';
    else 
        $newArray[$stringArray[$key-1]] = $value;
}

//var_dump($newArray);

?>
```

at the end you end up with an array with key=>value like this :

```
[
  "Bebouwde oppervlakte" => "80 M2"
  "Terras oppervlakte"   => "20 M2"
  "Keuken oppervlakte"   => "12 M2"
]
```

you can loop thru it and display as you want

Comment: I'll see how this works. If it works better then I'll give it a tick

Comment: Your original approach or answer you chose would need to be updated everytime the XML structure changes, for example he entered a new name that doesnt satisfy the if statement

Comment: The problem with this though is that all values get filtered. That does ***not*** need to happen.

Comment: @MarkdG, what do you mean by filtered?

Comment: They go out of the list into a new one conquetted onto each other. This does not need to happen.

Comment: @MarkdG, I made it easy to iterrate between your records, so if u wanna print out key next to value, you can just do :   
 foreach ($newArray as $key=>$value) { echo $key . ' - '. $value; }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225215/discussion-between-mark-dg-and-marwane-ezzaze).

Answer (score 0):

Because your sample input text only contains text which is to be kept, just use `preg_match_all()` to capture consecutive pairs of text, then use `array_column()` to form the pairs into an associative array. ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/Sens9))

```
preg_match_all(
    '/(\S+(?: \S+)*)\s+(\S+(?: \S+)*)/',
    $text,
    $m,
    PREG_SET_ORDER
);
var_export(array_column($m, 2, 1));
```

Output:

```
array (
  'Bebouwde oppervlakte' => '80 M2',
  'Terras oppervlakte' => '20 M2',
  'Keuken oppervlakte' => '12 M2',
)
```